# MindManager 10, 11 and 12 doesn't start in Windows 10

Tags: mind-manager

MindJet.com wants you to upgrade for $280+ to MindJet 2015. Older versions of their mind mapping products install into Windows 10 without any errors. However you can not start the application. When you try to, nothing happens, and there are no error messages, not even in the Windows event log.

Comment: While it does cover a (useful-to some) tool, this is not a strictly programming-related question. Hopefully this information is available and disseminated on the official support forums/site.

Answer (score 2):

The above steps didn't work for me, but I used the steps in this microsoft support note to enable .NET Framework 3.5 and after that was able to open and use my MindManager 9 version on my Microsoft Surface!

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-instal-net-framework-35-on-windows-10/450b3ba6-4d19-45ae-840e-78519f36d7a4?auth=1

To check if the.NET Framework 3.5 is available in Control Panel and to enable it, please follow these steps:

a) Press “Windows Logo” + “R” keys on the keyboard.

b) Type “appwiz.cpl” in the “Run” command box and press “ENTER”.

c) In the “Programs and Features” window, click on the link “Turn Windows features on or off”.

d) Check if the “.NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)” option is available in it.

e) If yes, then enable it and then click on “OK”.

f) Follow the on-screen instructions to complete the installation and restart the computer, if prompted.

This will install the .NET Framework 3.5 feature on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Support and sales do not tell or document this but you can get earlier versions to run in Windows 10. The older versions depend on older versions of .NET Frameworks. Windows 10 has .NET Framework 4.5 pre-installed but nothing older than that.

How to install the older .NET Framework versions in Windows 10:
Settings | Apps & Features | Manage Optional Features | Add a Feature |
Choose the .NET Framework 3.5, 3, 2 package install option. It should be the first in the list.

Your older versions of Mindjet/MindManager products will now run in Windows 10.